# Create connection string for MS-Access dynamically

Tags: c#, ms-access

How can we create a connection string to the Microsoft Access using C# programming dynamically? I tries the following code-

```
OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection();
String path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
con.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=" + path + "\\nik.mdb";
```

I got this result in response:

```
Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 55.
```

When i edit my string it looks as below:

```
Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=C:\Users\nikhil\desktop\nik.mdb
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "But got an error. " - that's, so ....informative....

Comment: @MitchWheat Should i print the error i got????

Comment: No, it's more fun if we have to guess....

Comment: You can use [OleDbConnectionStringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbconnectionstringbuilder.aspx) which gives you intellisense for available properties, and can construct the connection string with `.ToString()`.  You still have to get the `Provider` and `Data Source` settings exactly right, which can be finicky.

Comment: What does your connection string look like?

Comment: A wild guess appears...
It uses "Maybe you forgot user and password in the connection string..."
Wild guess waits if it was effective or not...

Comment: @mellamokb By using OleDbConnectionStringBuilder i cannot use the OledbCommand and OledbDataReader class.

Comment: @user1929236: That's not true.  You would just do `con.ConnectionString = myBuilder.ConnectionString`.  Also, [ConnectionStrings.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com/access) is a very good resource.

Comment: @W1ese1 I didn't use any username for it. It works well if i am giving it a static path. Like the complete path of the file.

Comment: @mellamokb thanks a lot. I forgot to use the last line. It worked for me. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Path.Combine` and a `OleDbConnectionStringBuilder` to create a valid connection-string:

```
var conString = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source={0}"
                             , Path.Combine(dir, "nik.mdb"));
var conBuilder = new OleDbConnectionStringBuilder(conString);
using (var con = new OleDbConnection(conBuilder.ConnectionString))
{
    // ...
}
```

Maybe you have white-spaces in the connection string.

**Update** Since you've edited your question and provided your connection-string. There is  a white-space between `OLEDB.4.0;` and `Data`. That might be  a possible reason for your exception. Then the `ConnectionStringBuilder` helps.

Comment: I just tested in LINQPad, and it works fine for me.  Using a space between `4.0;` and `Data Source` doesn't seem to make a difference either.

Comment: @mellamokb: Not sure if this causes the issue. But when i use the builder with his connection-string it removes the white-space. So this is just a wild guess, but at least it should help to increase readability and to be less error-prone (`Path.Combine`, `using-statement`).

Comment: Agreed.  It appears to me that a core piece of information is actually missing from the connection string.  http://connectionstrings.com/access shows that a workgroup database or password may be required.  I didn't need either in my test database, but some databases are setup with workgroup security.

Comment: The problem is not of the white spaces. It is due to the no use of the    OleDbConnectionStringBuilder    for the connection string

Comment: The `OleDbConnectionStringBuilder` is just a helper class. It generates a string for you when it's done, nothing else.  If you take the string it generates, and hard-coded it, it would work the same.  Can you paste what the Builder generated as the connection string?  There must be something different about it that caused it to work.

Comment: @user1929236: I can't follow. Your problem was that you haven't used the `OleDbConnectionStringBuilder`? Can you explain it further, does it work now?

Comment: @TimSchmelter Yes, i was creating the connection string as mentioned above in the post. But it was not working. I am new to the C# and knew only a bit about it. So, I tried searching but didn't find any result. So, i asked. So, the only thing that matters me is that I have lack of the knowledge about the subject. I used OledbConnectionBuilder and it really worked fr me.

Comment: @user1929236: Ok, but what was the reason, what does `conBuilder.ConnectionString` return in opposition to `conString`? Just for people with a similar problem in future.  You're welcome.